How can I set focus for navigation icon in material toolbar?
As of now the entire material toolbar is highlighted when the screen is entered but I need only on the navigation icon to receive focus.How can I do this?
I tried adding request focus to material toolbar.It didn't work.I also tried adding request focus to navigation icon.It didn't work either

Please, edit your question by adding CODE related to it. If possible, add the before and after the modification.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
